# What is the logic of jquery window.width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a signup form and whenever I click my input field, a modal has to open responsively. It's okey here on mobile it work's the way I want but if I resize my window nothing happens so I want to give you some example

[image]

[if you open my page on mobile](http://mobiletest.me/google_nexus_7_emulator/?u=http://firatabak.com/test/anasayfa.html) you are going to see that when you click, the modal is opening.

but if you resize the window to less than 768px and if click the input field the modal is not opening

JQUERY

```
var $window = $(window),
     $nogonder = $('.add-modal');

        if ($window.width() < 768) {
          $nogonder.on("click",function(){
            $("#parallaxPopup").modal('show');
          })

       }else{
        $nogonder.off("click");
        $("#parallaxPopup").modal('hide');
        $("#rezervasyonPopup").modal('hide');
        $("#popupCheckin").modal('hide');
       };
```

Comment: Your code is not executed again when you resize the window (the click listener isn't set). In order to do that, you can listen for the `resize` event and run you code again then. Ex `$( window ).resize(function() {/*run code again*/});`

Comment: @Titus how can I replace my code with window.resize my jquery is not well thanks

Comment: ouw sorry I did it and I tell you what happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in my comment. Currently, your code is executed only once probably when the page loads. In order to run your code again when the window is resized, you can do something like this:

```
function setModal(){
  var $window = $(window),
  $nogonder = $('.add-modal');

  if ($window.width() < 768) {
      $nogonder.on("click",function(){
        $("#parallaxPopup").modal('show');
      });
   } else {
      $nogonder.off("click");
      $("#parallaxPopup").modal('hide');
      $("#rezervasyonPopup").modal('hide');
      $("#popupCheckin").modal('hide');
   }
}
setModal();
$(window).resize(setModal);
```

Comment: thanks and if you are here I want to tell you another problem if you suitable another post ?

Comment: @ani_css If it is related to this problem, you can tell it to me here. If it doesn't, you can post another question.

Comment: problem is same shall I tell you here ?

Comment: @ani_css Yes, sure, post a comment.

Comment: before I start I have to tell you my english is not enough to tell something I'm sorry for this and I have another page (goo.gl/XfeTST) it has a fixed menu if you scroll page to down you are gonna see (I will continue to explain)

Comment: and if you try to scroll up my fixed menu is being non appear it's okey so here too.but if I resize my window and after resizing if I try to scroll up my fixed menu is not set non appear my Js code http://codepen.io/yedincifirat/pen/KggwxY

Comment: after resizing you are gonna test on wide screen

Comment: @ani_css I'm not sure I understand correctly. Is the problem the fact that the menu doesn't disappear (is not hidden) when you scroll to the top of the page ?

Comment: @ani_css Try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXXEvW The idea is to set the scroll function only once and to make changes to the page based on it's size. Don't set 2 scroll function to have one for each size, set only one and inside of it do different things based on the windows size. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I understand but I have no any experiement on jquery to do it and I tried your code nothing happend I'm trying to learn how to do and fix it problems I want to write new code for this event but I have no any idea.. thanks.

Comment: I tried another post but I can post after 90 minutes so thanks for your helping

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561226/fixed-navbar-issue-after-resize-to-page