# fixed navbar issue after resize to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[I have a page if you click you are gonna see demo page](http://firatabak.com/test/tur_detay.html) and there is a fixed menu which is hidden.

after scroll page to down you'll see fixed menu set as `display:block` as you see on image:
[image]
 but after appear if I'm resizing to window and if I turn normal desktop mode after scroll page to up as you see my fixed menu is not hiding

[image]

and another problem is if you open page mobile emulator (like on this emulator)[http://mobiletest.me/google_nexus_7_emulator/?u=http://firatabak.com/test/tur_detay.html] normally menu has to be show when I scroll page to down but it's not.

JS CODE

```
var navOffset = jQuery(".after-scroll-sticky").offset().top;
     jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollPosition = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollPosition >= navOffset){
            jQuery(".sticky-navbar").fadeIn().addClass("fixed");
        }else{
            jQuery(".sticky-navbar").fadeOut().removeClass("fixed");
        }
     }); 

        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                var navOffset2 = jQuery(".after-scroll-sticky").offset().top+200;
                 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
                        var sP = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
                        if(sP >= navOffset2){
                            $(".sticky-navbar").addClass("fadeOutRightBig");
                            $(".menu-btn").fadeIn("fast");
                        }else{
                            $(".sticky-navbar").removeClass("fadeOutRightBig");

                            $(".menu-btn").fadeOut("slow");
                        }
                 });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're defining the second `jQuery.scroll` function within an if statement, it only becomes active if the window width is less than 768px at the moment the script runs - it doesn't kick in when the window is resized. Instead you could try this format:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        // calculations and animation go here
    }
});
```

Or better yet, combine the two `jQuery.scroll` functions together:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

    var navOffset = jQuery(".after-scroll-sticky").offset().top,
        scrollPosition = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        if (scrollPosition >= navOffset + 200) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    else if (scrollPosition >= navOffset) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }

});
```

Then just make sure that you're undoing the changes made in other cases before applying the new changes.

Comment: yes I understand but I change my all js function but I have one more than scroll functions an that is why some js function is not working how can I combine properly ? and it's post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567151/how-to-combinecollect-all-scroll-functions