# Is there any way to combine (collect) all scroll functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have more than one scroll function like this:

FIRST

```
  $(document).scroll(function(){
        if(!$(".hotel-search-box").length){
            return false;
        }
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
          if (y > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top) {
            $('.sticky-checkin').show();
          } else {
            $('.sticky-checkin').hide();
          }
    });
```

SECOND

```
   $(document).scroll(function() {
      if (!$("#aniStickyNav").length) {
     return false; //Check if the element exist
  }
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > $(".after-scroll-sticky").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height()) {
    $('#aniStickyNav').show();
  } else {
    $('#aniStickyNav').hide();
  }
});
```

THIRD

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    backToTop();
});
```

I tried this way:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
       function siziArayalim(){
           var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > 800) {
        $('.sizi-arayalim').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('.sizi-arayalim').fadeOut();
      }
    }
 function aniStickyNav(){
         if (!$("#aniStickyNav").length) {
            return false; //Check if the element exist
        }
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > $(".after-scroll-sticky").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height()) {
        $('#aniStickyNav').show();
      } else {
        $('#aniStickyNav').hide();
      }
    }

function stickyCheckin(){
     if(!$(".hotel-search-box").length){
        return false;
    }
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top) {
        $('.sticky-checkin').show();
      } else {
        $('.sticky-checkin').hide();
      }
}
  siziArayalim();
  aniStickyNav();
  stickyCheckin();
});
```

but nothing works.

Because of more than one scroll function some js functions are not working as expected that is why I wonder that how to combine all `window.scroll` function in a just one function healthy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code, first one is that you declare your functions inside the scroll function. This is not OK for performance. The second one is $(this) you are using inside the functions. I don't know what "this" is. In that context you are using, this will be the window object but i don't think that's what you need. Need more info here.

```
function siziArayalim(){
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
        $('.sizi-arayalim').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.sizi-arayalim').fadeOut();
    }
}

function aniStickyNav(){
    if (!$("#aniStickyNav").length) {
        return false; //Check if the element exist
    }
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > $(".after-scroll-sticky").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height()) {
        $('#aniStickyNav').show();
    } else {
        $('#aniStickyNav').hide();
    }

    return true;
}


function stickyCheckin(){
    if(!$(".hotel-search-box").length){
        return false;
    }
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top) {
        $('.sticky-checkin').show();
    } else {
        $('.sticky-checkin').hide();
    }

    return true;
}


$(window).scroll(function(){
    siziArayalim();

    // check if the functions return false, if not, continue
    if(!aniStickyNav()){
        return false;
    }

    if(!stickyCheckin()){
        return false;
    }
});
```